# AWS Java SDK DynamoDB update expression for a "complex" item

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

So I have the following item where **testId** is the sort key:

```
{
 "userId": "admin",
 "testId": "1234",
 "picture": "abstract",
 "numOfUsers": 1,
 "Tests": [
  {
   "duration": 1234,
   "typeId": "2345",
   "interval": 450000,
   "quantity": 333333
  },
  {
   "duration": 1234,
   "typeId": "6789",
   "interval": 450000,
   "quantity": 333333
  },
  {
   "duration": 1234,
   "typeId": "2020",
   "interval": 450000,
   "quantity": 333333
  }
 ]
}
```

As you can see, there are a few identical items under tests. My question is how do I update all of them with the same value? What I mean by that is that, for example, I would like to update duration on all three objects from 1234 to 2222.

Here is the code I've tested:

```
    Table table = dynamoDB.getTable(tableName);
    Map<String, String> expressionAttributeNames = new HashMap<String, String>();
    expressionAttributeNames.put("#A", "Duration");

    Map<String, Object> expressionAttributeValues = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    expressionAttributeValues.put(":val1", "2222");

    UpdateItemOutcome outcome =  table.updateItem(
            "testId",         
             "1234",           
            "set #A :val1", 
            expressionAttributeNames,
            expressionAttributeValues);
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: 1. `testId` is your sort key - what is your partition key? 2. *few identical items under tests* - identical in terms of what? duration? 3. does this need to be universal aka. change all dupes (by duration I presume)? will you know the IDs of the dupes beforehand? if not, you will need to get the item first to then check for dupes; we need more info please :)

Comment: My partition key is userId and its mostly identical on all items. I mean identical as far as keys, they all share duration, typeId, interval and quantity. By dups you mean duplications? Yes, duration (the key of which value I'd like to update) is always the same on all three objects under "tests". I can always get the item as json and then update it using jason path but there must be an elegant way to do this using Table.updateItem

Comment: if this is your intent, you might consider a different dynamo strategy. Perhaps PK of test name, SK of the date of the tests (if you are running the test more than once a day, or some other value that would result in many tests together that you could search against) and then each atribute is a Map type attribute with the attribute name of the test ID, containing the json of the test.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding of DynamoDb and Expressions, is that you need to tell dynamodb to drill into the attribute you want.

Your code is telling it to update Duration...but where is Duration?  It is not at the top level of the item.

See if this would work:

```
Table table = dynamoDB.getTable(tableName);
    Map<String, String> expressionAttributeNames = new HashMap<String, String>();
expressionAttributeNames.put("#Dur", "duration");
expressionAttributeNames.put("#Test", "Tests");


Map<String, Object> expressionAttributeValues = new HashMap<String, Object>();
expressionAttributeValues.put(":val1", "2222");

UpdateItemOutcome outcome =  table.updateItem(
        "testId",         
         "1234",           
        "set #Test.#Dur :val1", 
        expressionAttributeNames,
        expressionAttributeValues);
```

=== Edited ===

```
ValueMap valueMap = new ValueMap().withNumber(":dur", 2222));

UpdateItemSpec updateItemSpec = new UpdateItemSpec()
      .withPrimaryKey("key", year)
      .withUpdateExpression("set Tests.duration = :dur")
      .withValueMap(valueMap)
      .withReturnValues(ReturnValue.UPDATED_NEW);

UpdateItemOutcome updateItemOutcome = table.updateItem(updateItemSpec);
```

=== Edited ====

```
UpdateItemSpec updateItemSpec = new UpdateItemSpec()
    .withPrimaryKey("key", "primaryKey")
    .withUpdateExpression("set Tests.#duration = :value")
    .withNameMap(new NameMap().with("#duration", "duration"))
    .withValueMap(new ValueMap().withNumber(":value", 2222))
    .withReturnValues(ReturnValue.UPDATED_NEW);
```

Comment: I tried but I am getting the following exception: com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AmazonDynamoDBException: Invalid UpdateExpression: Syntax error; token: ":val1", near: "#Dur :val1" (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: 4H22J173OT44A8VDVMSQA80CQBVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG; Proxy: null)

Comment: can you try the edit @PloniStacker

Comment: Thanks, now getting - com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AmazonDynamoDBException: Invalid UpdateExpression: Attribute name is a reserved keyword; reserved keyword: duration (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: 2HNL4I4NGEEOO1EC4OLNIGDQRRVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG; Proxy: null)

Comment: Lets try the last edit @PloniStacker :)